# asp.net refresh other web form griview

Tags: asp.net

Hi and thanks for attention to my problems.
i have a two web form in my project and in webform1 have a gridview and button,when i click the webform1 button page open with under simple code:

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('MaterialEditSelect.aspx?name=" + row.Cells[2].Text + "&value=" + row.Cells[3].Text + "&id=" + row.Cells[4].Text + "','newwindow','height=50px','width=50px');</script>");
```

and when go to webform2 i change the database data and save,but when i close the webform2 and return to webform1 i see the before information into gridview,now i want when close the webform2 ,gridview refresh into webform1.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this** - Use **[window.opener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp)**

- WebForm2.aspx

`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function RefreshParent() {
            if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
                window.opener.location.reload();
                window.close(); // ADDED LINE
            }
        }
        window.onbeforeunload = RefreshParent;
</script>`
```

- Put above code in your `webform2.aspx` in `<head>` tag at top of the page.

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi - Check the above answer

Comment: Hi @Prog ,it's work but my webform2 refresh rapidly and can not close the web form2

Comment: How r u displaying/binding the data. Are you using datasets? If yes, you have to reload the content. Try putting the grid into 1 iframe & reload it from JS rather than refreshing entire page.

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi  - Do you got any message or alert while you closing Webform2 ?

Comment: @Prog my problem in webform2,when close the webform2,webform2 automatic reopen!

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi  - Okay I got the issue !! ...your webform2 is reopen again and again because you wrote `Response.Write("<script>window.open('MaterialEditSelect.aspx?name=" + row.Cells[2].Text + "&value=" + row.Cells[3].Text + "&id=" + row.Cells[4].Text + "','newwindow','height=50px','width=50px');</script>");` in your **`Page_Loag`** event

Comment: @Prog Yes ,in internet explorer i get this message box when close the webform2 ,your browser need to resend request to refresh page,but this message not show in google chrome!

Comment: @Prog no my friend o write this code in webform1 button click to redirect to webform2 :Response.Write("<script>window.open('MaterialEditSelect.aspx?name=" + row.Cells[2].Text + "&value=" + row.Cells[3].Text + "&id=" + row.Cells[4].Text + "','newwindow','height=50px','width=50px');</script>");

Comment: @Prog MaterialEditSelect.aspx==my webform2

Comment: @Prog i check,when click into the selectrow gridview into webform1 and open webform2,when close the webform2,gridview selectrow event run again automatic!

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi  I thinks you have to use ` window.close(); ` at the end of `window.opener.location.reload();` this line in above code.

Comment: @Prog my friend thanks,but i check my code,explain fully:in my webform 1 i have a gridview,and gridview have a autogeneratedSelect button and when i click select button into gridview,window "webform2" open and edit the database table and when close webform2,in the webform1 row select gridview active and automatic open the webform2.